# In Python using three functions in a loop where the third's output is new input for all three

Tags: python, function, loops, input, output

I think the best way to describe what I am trying to solve is as follows:

I have a loop of three functions, where initially the input value is given by the user, say `input1`. Then the first two functions, say `function1` and `function2` use this input to create a number, say `output1` and `output2`.

Then the third function also takes the initially given input value and now uses `output1` and `output2` to alter the input, making it `input2`.

Now I want to do it all again, but using `input2` as the new input for all three functions. For some reason I can't make this happen in Python. Since it will always use that initially given input value for the functions.

I made `output1` and `output2` global, so it can be used in `function3`. `function3` returns a 'new' `input1`, which I want as input for the next iteration, but that doesn't work.

```
def function1(input1):
    global output1
    output1 = input1 * 3
    return output1

def function2(input1):
    global output2
    output2 = input1 * 4
    return output2

def function3(input1):
    output3 = input1 * output1 * output2
    input1=output3
    return input1

input1 = float(raw_input('Please give some input number: '))

for i in range(2):
    function1(input1)
    function2(input1)
    function3(input1)
```

If I enter the value '2' the first iteration, that gives:

> output1 becomes 6
>
> output2 becomes 8
>
> output3 becomes 96

Then for iteration 2 I would expect 96 as an input, and thus

> output1 becomes 288
>
> output2 becomes 384
>
> output3 becomes 10616832.

But instead, it just iterates the first loop, with the exact same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the input variable after `function3` runs as such:

```
for i in range(2):
    function1(input1)
    function2(input1)
    input1 = function3(input1)
```

Edit: I think you're trying to do two different things at the same time. You are trying to make `output1` and `output2` global so that `function3` can refer to it. However, you are also returning `output1` and `output2`, as if they aren't global but rather should be passed by value to the local scope. As a general rule of thumb, global variables should be used only when absolutely necessary. Global variables can be read/written over by anyone, making it difficult to track what the value is and who changed it last. Very hard to debug. Let's just make everything local variables by catching values that your functions already `return`.

```
def function1(x):
    return x * 3

def function2(x):
    return x * 4

def function3(x, y, z):
    return x * y * z

input1 = float(input('Please give some input number: '))

for i in range(2):
    output1 = function1(input1)
    output2 = function2(input1)
    input1 = function3(input1, output1, output2)
    print(input1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer! This makes sense. So just for my understanding: if I make something 'global' it is, from that point, transcendent throughout the entire program. If I keep it local, it is only used inside the function itself. Is that a correct understanding? Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: I mean, I think some reading for global vs local scope would be smart, as any quick summary is sure to leave out the details. But in your case, using the same variable name inside a function as the global variable does not make that variable global automatically. `input1` in function3 of your original code is not the same variable as `input1` in your global part, which is why it wasn't updating the original input. Watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-CoVBK_bLE&feature=youtu.be